# how to store images in unique folder(using primary key) for each upload using multer in nest js

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have an application where i want to store multipart form data along with image. I want images to be stored in unique folder which is primary id. How can i do it.

Here i am saving multiform data in database. I want to use primary id return by below function to create folder to save its respective images.

```
    async createFaceDetection(faceDetectionReqDto: FaceDetectionReqDto): Promise<Object> {
try {
    const newFaceDetection = new face_detection({
        Name: faceDetectionReqDto.Name
    })
    const savedMediaUpload = await this.FaceDetectionRepository.save(newFaceDetection);
    return savedMediaUpload
}
catch (err) {
    throw err;
}
}
```

how can i use primary id fetched by "savedMediaUpload" variable in multer

*my component.controller.ts code*

```
   @UseInterceptors(
  FilesInterceptor('Images', 20,
   {

storage: diskStorage({
  destination: async function (req, file, cb) {
    const filePath = path.join(ROOT_DIR, FACE_DETECTION_PATH, {Primary-Id}) // (primary id   
  generated by above function.)
    if (!existsSync(`${filePath}`)) { mkdirSync(filePath, { recursive: true }) }
    cb(null, filePath);
  },
  filename: (_req, file, cb) => {
    return cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
}),
}),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done it like this, by appending generated UUID to the file name - may not be perfect but works good enough for me so far:

Controller:

```
@UseInterceptors(
    FilesInterceptor('asset', 10, {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: UPLOADS_DIR,
        filename: getUniqueFileName,
      }),
      limits: {
        fileSize: MAX_FILE_SIZE_BYTES,
      },
      fileFilter: validateImageFile,
    }),
  )
  @Post()
  async createAsset(
    @Body() assetCreateRequest: AssetCreateRequest,
    @UploadedFile() asset: UploadedFileModel,
  ): Promise<AssetResponse[]> {
    ....
  }
```

And `getUniqueFileName` looks like this:

```
import { extname } from 'path';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

import { UploadedFileModel } from '../../dto/internal/file-upload';

export const getUniqueFileName = (
  _request: unknown,
  file: UploadedFileModel,
  callback: (error: Error | null, fileName: string) => void,
) => {
  const name = file.originalname.split('.')[0];
  const extension = extname(file.originalname);
  const randomUuid = uuidv4();
  callback(null, `${name}-${randomUuid}${extension}`);
};
```

Later on in the database, I have separate `Asset` and e.g. `User` tables where `User` references a record in the `Asset` table by foreign key, and `Asset` record contains all the necessary info - file name, path, URL etc.

Comment: Thank you.. But i want to generate unique folder using primary id